# How to differentiate when the web is opened in an in-app browser or in a regular browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent, inappbrowser

I am trying to show content based on where the web is being opened.
For example if it's a normal browser then show X and if it is being opened in an in-app browser then show Y.

i have tried to detect the browser user agents.. and if it's not browser agent then it is an in-app browser.

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

if (userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
    return "Mozilla Firefox";
} else if (userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
     return "Google Chrome";
} else if (userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
     return "Apple Safari";
} else if (userAgent.indexOf("Opera") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("OPR") > -1) {
     return "Opera";
} else if (userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
     return "Microsoft Edge";
} else if (userAgent.indexOf("Trident") > -1) {
     return "Internet Explorer";
} else {
     return "In-App Browser";
}
```

The above code works fine for browser detection and it also works fine for apps line facebook, instagram, twitter but it failed for apps like slack.

I consoled the user agent of slack in-app browser ... it was same as a normal browser.
so it failed there.

Is there any way which can find out if web is being opened in in-app browser or not?

Answer (score 0):

**Comments**

- There is no standard way to identify if it is an app
- You could attempt to look for `"signs"` that it is being used in an app by looking at: `navigator`, `navigator.plugins`, `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, `window`, `document`, `document.cookie`
- You could also parse headers sent to the server and see if the app passes any custom headers that identify it as an app.

**Examples**

```
// Check for Google Tag Manager API exists
if ( window.gtag ){
    // .... do something ...
}

// Check if brave browser
if ( navigator.brave ){
    // .... do something ...
}

// Check if jQuery is used
if ( window.jQuery ){
    // .... do something ...
}
```